# WindowsIotCore Raspberry Pi UWP Serial port access issue(System.AccessViolationException)

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to use the serial pin of the Raspberry Pi 3 for input for a UWP app on the WindowsIotCore platform. I keep getting this exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an 
indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

The code where this exception occurs is:

```
SerialDevice serialPort = null;
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
```

Update:
I created a new UWP project and used the same code, on the same platform, on the same Raspberry Pi, using the same development PC, the code worked fine then.

Comment: Check the return value of those `await`ed function calls -- pretty sure you get a `TResult`, not the actual type you're expecting

Comment: After debugging i found out that the code gives the exception whenever the serialPort variable's property is called and set,
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);
this command should set the serialPort variable as the chosen serial device, but instead the variable stays null
I also used this same could in a new project on the same platform, it worked perfectly fine then

Comment: @daniyalselani If SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id) retrun null you need to check the device capability(    `<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>`) is added to package.appxmanifest or not.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, I had already edited the package.appxmanifest file through visual studio, however i checked again and for some reason, any edits made to the file through visual studio were not being saved. After using an external editor to edit the file, i found no issue with my code. The issue is solved now. Thank you

Comment: Hi daniyal, the issue solve and you can accept your solution as answer. How to accetp an answer you can reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by editing the package.appxmanifest file using notepad++
I had already edited the package.appxmanifest file through visual studio 2017, however i checked again and for some reason, any edits made to the file through visual studio 2017 were not being saved. After using an external editor to edit the file, i found no issue with my code. The issue is solved now.

Comment: It is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/SerialUART/CS/README.md#lets-look-at-the-code):  "Visual Studio 2017 has a known bug in the Manifest Designer that affects the serialcommunication capability. If your appxmanifest adds the serialcommunication capability, modifying your appxmanifest with the designer will corrupt your appxmanifest (the Device xml child will be lost). You can workaround this problem by hand editing the appxmanifest by right-clicking your appxmanifest and selecting View Code from the context menu."